# I (hear, not) _____ the song in years

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

> A) I (hear, not) _____ the song in years.
>   B) I (hear, not) _____ the song in years, and when I heard it I cried.

If I have understood correctly the differences of these two Tenses, in the *first sentence* we've to use *Present Perfect*, because we are talking about an action that has an influence on the present.

> Answer A): I haven't heard the song in years.

And in the *second sentence* we've to use *Past Perfect* because we are talking about an action that took place once before another point in the past.

> Answer B): I hadn't heard the song in years, and when I heard it I cried.

Comment: So, what's your question. You seem to have gotten this...

Comment: I wasn't sure if I had understood correctly the main difference of these tenses.

Answer (score 2):

It's as you say.

We are more likely to use the present when talking or writing about the song:

> I really loved the song; I haven't heard it played in years.

We prefer the past perfect when referring back to it and then to our reactions or some other subsequent event:

> I hadn't heard the song in years; it brought back wonderful memories.

Your examples make the point.